# How to use Jest with React and Webpack

Tags: facebook, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I was trying to configure Jest to work with React and Webpack. With the way I use Webpack aliases and ES6 modules exports, I had huge problems configuring it.

Since no other questions worked for me, I want to show you what I did to be able to use Jest with ReactJs and Webpack.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My mainly problem was that I was using ES6 to export my modules and I needed a preprocessor to handle the imports.

Given that basic component:

```
import 'Incription.scss';

import React from 'react;
import InscriptionModal from './InscriptionModal';

class Inscription extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return <InscriptionModal />;
    }
}

export default Inscription;
```

Test looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import Inscription from './Inscription';

describe('Inscription', () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {
        const tree = renderer.create(<Inscription />).toJSON();

        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

With no configuration in *package.json*, when I was running the test I always ended up with:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Basically, I needed to handle asset files and, to do so, I needed to change my *package.json* jest config using [moduleNameMapper](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-webpack.html).:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/cfg/mocks/fileMock.js",
      "^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/cfg/mocks/styleMock.js"
    }
}
```

*fileMock.js*

```
module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

*styleMock.js*

```
module.exports = {};
```

Next problem was that Jest could not handle the modules of ES6 so, I needed a preprocessor. The exact error was:

```
Cannot find module './InscriptionModal' from 'Inscription.spec.js'
```

I found a plugin called [jest-webpack-alias](https://github.com/mwolson/jest-webpack-alias) that it was doing that so, I changed again the jest configuration of my *package.json*:

```
"jest": {
    ...
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/cfg/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "jest-webpack-alias": {
        "configFile": "cfg/jest.js"
    },
}
```

And my preprocessor.js file looked like:

```
const babelJest = require('babel-jest');

require('babel-register');
const webpackAlias = require('jest-webpack-alias');

module.exports = {
  process: function (src, filename) {
    if (filename.indexOf('node_modules') === -1) {
      src = babelJest.process(src, filename);
      src = webpackAlias.process(src, filename);
    }
    return src;
  }
};
```

Notice the configFile of jest-webpack-file in my *package.json*. It has a route of my webpack test configuration. The file looked like this:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

const srcPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../src/');
const baseConfig = require('./base');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|css|sass|scss|less|styl)$/,
      loader: 'null-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      include: [].concat(
        baseConfig.additionalPaths,
        [
          path.join(__dirname, '/../src'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/../test')
        ]
      )
    }, {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, '/../src'),
    extensions: [
      '',
      '.js',
      '.jsx'
    ],
    alias: {
      actions: `${srcPath}/actions/`,
      components: `${srcPath}/components/`,
      sources: `${srcPath}/sources/`,
      stores: `${srcPath}/stores/`,
      services: `${srcPath}/services/`,
      styles: `${srcPath}/styles/`,
      i18n: `${srcPath}/i18n/`,
      config: `${srcPath}/config/test`,
      utils: `${srcPath}/utils/`,
      vendor: `${srcPath}/vendor/`,
      images: `${srcPath}/images/`
    }
  }
};
```

It's very important in this file to add the root of your project because if not, you will have this error:

```
Missing setting "resolve.modules" (webpack v2) or "resolve.root" (webpack v1) in...
```

With the configs added, you now can mock your imports using [Jest mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options):

```
jest.mock('./InscriptionModal, () => {
  return {};
});
```

It's important to add the param [--no-cache](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/troubleshooting.html#caching-issues) when running tests because Jest caches transformed module files to speed up test execution.

Another annoying bug is when you're trying to add [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) or [React Test Utils](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html) in your tests. It prints this error:

```
Invariant Violation: ReactCompositeComponent: injectEnvironment() can only be called once.
```

What you [have to do](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1353#issuecomment-237176147) is add in your tests this line of code:

```
jest.mock('react/lib/ReactDefaultInjection');
```

I hope you find useful!

**UPDATE**

[Upgrading](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/11/16/react-v15.4.0.html) React and React-dom to v15.4.0 fixes latest bug commented.